# Erro ao mandar e-mail

Tags: c#, email, smtp

Eu estou com um erro chato, não consigo resolver faz uns dias.

Eu procurei, mas não achei nada a respeito de como removê-lo.

**Erro:**

> O servidor SMTP requer uma conexão segura ou o cliente não foi
>   autenticado. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.5.1 Authentication
>   Required. Learn more at

**Código:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace email
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MailMessage email;
        Stopwatch stop =  new Stopwatch();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        email = new MailMessage();
        email.To.Add(new MailAddress(textBox1.Text)); 
        email.From = new MailAddress(textBox3.Text); 
        email.Subject = textBox2.Text; 
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;
        email.Body = textBox5.Text; 
        SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient(); 
        cliente.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        cliente.Port = 587;
        using (cliente)
        {
            cliente.Credentials  = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text); //credenciais, senha e email
            cliente.EnableSsl = true;
            cliente.Send(email); 
        }
        MessageBox.Show("email enviado");

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o usuário e senha informados em tela não estão sendo efetivamente considerados para autenticação no servidor SMTP.

Tente complementar setando a propriedade **UseDefaultCredentials** para `false`:

```
using (SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient())
{
  cliente.Credentials  = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text); 
  cliente.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  cliente.Port = 587;
  cliente.EnableSsl = true;
  cliente.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // Aqui!!
  cliente.Send(email); 
}
```

Comment: Também não funcionou, cara. Tentei trocar pra console e até fiz outro formulário, mesmo colocando as credenciais certas, acontece esse erro.

Comment: Você está utilizando qual versão do .NET? E qual é o sistema operacional da máquina onde vc está executando a aplicação? Talvez seja uma questão de versão do TLS...